# Creating routes for Ajax calls in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

let's say I have this route for my rendered HTML:

```
app.get('/profile/:id', function (req, res) { // my route
    res.render('profile', { id: Number(req.params.id) }); // render the file and set a variable
});
```

and in my client side javascript file for the profile page I want to get data from the server. I request the data when loading the page by sending a user id to the server and the server returns a user object:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var user = null;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '', // This one is missing here
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(data){
        user = JSON.stringify(data);
    });

    console.log(user.name);

});
```

And my server would handle this function:

```
app.get('', function (req, res) { // missing route
    var userId = ; // This is missing
    var userObj = getUserById(userId);
    res.send(userObj);
});
```

What route do I have to use? Tutorials say I have to pass in the route like `/profile/:id` but this route already exists?

I tried defining a new route like:

```
app.get('/reqUser/:id', function (req, res) { // Ajax  route
    res.send(getUserById(Number(req.params.id)));
});
```

and for my Ajax call I pass in the url `http://localhost:8888/reqUser/12345` but this seems to be wrong because user is still null after using the Ajax call.

So how can I define a route handling the page and the Ajax call?

Comment: What would be the difference between ajax output  and page render? Not really clear what you want to accomplish here

Comment: user is still null so I thought my Ajax call is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** First off, you'll want to fix the bug in your client-side JS, where you are attempting to print `user.name` before `user` has been fetched from the server. You can fix this by moving your `console.log` statement into the `done()` callback like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var user = null;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '', // This one is missing here
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(data){
        user = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(user.name); // log here 
    });

});
```

Regarding your routes question, you have several options. Below are two common solutions to this problem:

- Create a separate `api` route to distinguish your API requests from your page requests. For example, `app.get('/api/profile/:id, (req, res) => {...});'`
- Add a URL parameter to your AJAX calls specifying the format you want the response to be in, with the default being the page's HTML. For example, your AJAX would send a GET request to the URL `/profile/2012?format=json`, which would return the profile's information in JSON.

Personally, I prefer the first option, as it makes intent more clear.

Comment: sorry, would you mind specifying the first way? I'm a total beginner...

Comment: Sure! I’ll expand on option 1 when I’m back home in about an hour or so. In the meantime, see my note about the bug in your client-side JS

Comment: Making the fix to your client-side JS will print the `user.name` correctly if you make the Ajax call to a valid route.

Comment: I just fixed the Ajax callback. But when will I be able to use variables when requesting them in the call? I assigned a local variable to `user.name` and it is still undefined, but in the callback it's not

Comment: The only safe place to access `user.name` is inside your callback, so you'll either need to move all of your logic into `done()`, or better yet, you can place all of the logic in a function, and then call that function inside your `done()`

Comment: ok, I have this example code here https://pastebin.com/NYr4ZjV6 how can I edit the code if I want to have the variable being accessible for client side functions? When I press a button, the value is still null, so how do I get the value from the Ajax Callback =?

Comment: sorry,  there was a mistake in the script, I updated it: https://pastebin.com/xaHwxCT5

Comment: You'll call `increaseValue` directly after line 7, which is inside of your `done()` callback. Also, you might want to move line 11 to before line 2 so that the variable is declared before it is used.